# Menu Mini Panels Contain Views Content

Tags: 7, routes

I am trying to add mega menu to my website. For the mega menu, i am using menu mini panels. But, i am a bit confused to use it. What i need is: adding views content to the mega menu. But, after i read some of references, i don't really understand about how to do it in a simple way. Here is the display that i want to achieve:

-left sidebar -- mineral block -- mouse over -- display mega menu (contain views content).

Anyone could help me? Thank you.